# Android new boston tutorial app not working

Tags: android

i am going through the newboston tutorial for learning to program android devices and in the very initial videos itself i am stuck.

While trying to execute my app on the eclipse emulator,i am getting this error that the app has stopped working.

Can anyone please help me with this.

This is what the logger says

```
           09-30 18:43:45.738: E/AndroidRuntime(627): java.lang.RuntimeException:
  Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.vivek.helloworld/com.vivek.helloworld.MainActivity}: 
  android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0


 09-30 18:43:44.478: E/Trace(627): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
```

Comment: You would need to post the code but I'm assuming you have something like, `tv.setText(someVariable)` where `someVariable` is an `int`

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right,its display.setText(counter),where counter is an int

Comment: **Off-topic:** in the future, please post the **full** stacktrace and the most relevant code (not all code) when your app crashes. This one was easy because I've seen it so many times but usually we need more info.

Comment: Yes i will surely post the entire stack trace next time i encounter any issue.Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write

```
display.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
```

instead of

```
display.setText(counter);
```

Comment: Alright i will try,just curious to know,like even  i knew that this might be an error,but while trying to execute the code,why their was no error that was thrown for this mistake

Comment: See the linked post above. There are multiple `setText()` methods so the compiler doesn't know you are using the wrong one

Comment: This is a correct answer but adding an explanation as to *why* it is correct would make it much more helpful for folks